# Multidimensional array values to string in C++

Tags: c++

I have an array that contains elements with the following structure:

```
struct xyz { float x; float y; float z; };
```

How could I save all values into string using one or two lines? I am using now a `for` loop and accessing each position as `world[i].x, world[i].y, world[i].z` successfully, but it takes so much time...

Added: I am saving it now into txt as follows but running a loop for each array position and consuming a lot of execution time. If more details are required please let me know.

```
   POINT world[1280];

    fillArrayWithData(world);

    for (int i=0;i<width;i++)
    {
        fs<<world[i].x<<" "<<world[i].y<<" "<<world[i].z;
    }
```

Comment: Do you want the answer in C or C++? The answers are quite radically different for the two languages. You won't be able to do much better than a `for` loop — C++ might disguise it with iterators etc so you write one line of code, but you're calling functions. With the right support functions, it is a couple of lines of C code.

Comment: prefer in c++. Thank you

Comment: Less lines of code won't magically give you better performance. Show us your code so we can see how can it be made faster.

Comment: Takes so much time - Do you mean time to execute, time to type, time to compile? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: What is this unit of measurement you are attempting to use?  So much time for ... what?

Comment: It is not clear what is the format of the string. How are you going to save values in a string?

Comment: What do you do with the file after it was written? Do you eventually read it back into the application?

Comment: no, file is saved to be used for another program but it should not affect. I have problems on cycle time writing line by line.

Comment: Have you tried writing the floats as 32-bit binary fields? It will introduce possible endianess and format issues between machines, but those can be coped with. This would get rid of the convert-to-string operation which could inc speed... not sure by how much tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried binary save?

```
fs.write(world[i], sizeof(POINT));
...
```

It'll be machine-dependent though (like @Jimbo suggested)

Comment: IMO, this a very peculiar suggestion as it does not really involve strings at all (and the character array is neither guaranteed to be null terminated nor guaranteed not to contain intermediate null bytes).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I agree, I'll modify